# Mac Appstore (on Mojave) issues

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore, mojave

When I type my email and password and then click the login button, after a few seconds I am returned to the login button and not logged in. Please help ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

ok so after an hour on the phone with Apple this is what worked:  Simply sign out of your iCloud, reboot your machine and then sign into the Mac App Store before signing into iCloud.